# Regarding IMPORTHTML Function

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I am Using IMPORTHTML Function:

```
=IMPORTHTML("https://thefreedictionary.com/"&A1, "table")
```

However, the results come in a lot of cells. I have a list of things to do that, so I would need it to come in one single cell. Is there a way to retrieve the whole table in one single cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following.

```
=QUERY(TRANSPOSE(ARRAYFORMULA(CONCAT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IMPORTHTML("https://thefreedictionary.com/"&A1&"&in=","table",0)),,9^9),CHAR(10)))),,9^9)
```